# Need help parsing JSON decoded grandchildren with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, grandchild

```
foreach($response_2['items'] as $item) {
$item['track']['name'] = (array)$item['track']['name'];
foreach($item['track']['name'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
$item['track']['artists']['name'] = (array)$item['track']['artists']['name'];
foreach($item['track']['artists']['name'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
} 
$item['track']['duration_ms'] = (array)$item['track']['duration_ms'];
foreach($item['track']['duration_ms'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
    } 
}
```

...to parse this response: http://pastebin.com/uxBF3Kxe# (after I've decoded it).

All the values for `['track']['name']` and `['track']['duration_ms']` are echoed correctly, but nothing is echoed for `['track']['artists']['name']`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['track']['artists']` is array :)

Try this ;)

```
foreach($item['track']['artists'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Btw...
This is better solution ;)

```
$response_2 = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($response_2['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['track']['name'] . "<br />";

    foreach($item['track']['artists'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['name'] . "<br />";
    }

    echo $item['track']['duration_ms'] . "<br />";
}
```

/**** Added separator *****/

```
$response_2 = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($response_2['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['track']['name'] . "<br />";

    echo implode(',', array_map(
            function ($value) {
                return $value['name'];
            },
            $item['track']['artists']
        )
    );

    echo "<br />";

    echo $item['track']['duration_ms'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That worked great! What if I want to separate those values with `","` instead of `"<br />"`? I guess I need to make some kind of IF statement in there since I don't want the last value to have a `","` after it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! THANKS! :)
Do you also know how I can convert the value for ['duration_ms'] from milliseconds to MM:SS?

Comment: `echo date('i:s', $item['track']['duration_ms'] / 1000) . "<br />";`

Comment: Dude, I love you! :) Thank you very much for your help, it was appreciated!